# Randomizing Instances Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

So I built a geometry node setup that lets me build houses out of different shapes I made.In my geonode setup I just put all the parts together dependent on size and all.
[image]

And now I want to use that group to make different buildings on a grid but so far I only get the same instance back.Is there a quick fix or do I need to set up every house variation myself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you only have one set of geometry that can be instanced on your points. You can use the [*Geometry to Instance*-node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/geometry_to_instance.html) and multiple copies of your group to create more variants:
[image: Using the Geometry to Instance-node to instance a cube or an ico sphere on a grid]